# Specifying Cell format for WritableHyperlink using jxl for java

Tags: java, jxl

I'm using jxl(a Java based API for MS excel file manipulation) to create excel reports. I'm inserting the hyperlink like this

```
//sheet is WritableSheet
//adding hyperlink to cell 0,0 of the sheet
WritableHyperlink hl = new WritableHyperlink(0, 0, "http://www.google.com", "home page");
sheet.addHyperlink(hl);
```

This works fine, but it displays the data in default cell format, which is white colored cell and blue font. Is there any way by which I can specify cell format for this hyperlink like it is done for a label or number. This is important because this hyperlink opens the error screenshot, so as per the specification the cell should be in Red color.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a label formatted how you'd like for the same cell as the hyperlink, e.g.:

```
    WritableHyperlink hl = new WritableHyperlink(0, 0, 
            new URL("http://www.google.com"));
    sheet.addHyperlink(hl);

    WritableFont redFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL);
    redFont.setColour(Colour.RED);
    WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(redFont);
    Label label = new Label(0, 0, "home page", cellFormat);
    sheet.addCell(label);
```

Comment: Earlier, I thought that writing label to same cell would overwrite the hyperlink but this is not true.Thanks for the info.